# Product of standard simplices based on Eilenberg-Zilber theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, simplicial-stuff

I am trying to find an explanation for the claim that the Eilenberg-Zilber theorem implies the isomorphism

$$\mathsf{Hom}_{\mathbf{sSet}}(\Delta\left[n\right] \times \Delta\left[1\right], L) \cong \mathsf{Hom}_{\mathbf{sSet}}(\Delta\left[n + 1\right], L),$$

where $\Delta\left[k\right]$ denotes the standard $k$-simplex.

I am familiar with the classical form of the theorem for singular chains, but I have been unable to use it for this isomorphism. Could anyone explain the proof for me or point me to a reference?

Comment: This does not look right. If the isomorphism were natural it would imply $\Delta^n \times \Delta^1 \cong \Delta^{n+1}$, which is false.

Comment: @ZhenLin Why is it false?

Comment: Well, $\Delta^n \times \Delta^1$ has $2 n + 2$ vertices, but $\Delta^{n+1}$ has $n + 2$ vertices. Or you can draw pictures.

Comment: @ZhenLin I thought those two spaces are homeomorphic. Are you saying they're not, because they have different numbers of vertices?

Comment: @ZhenLin They are homeomorphic, but not simplicially isomorphic.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 You are asking about simplicial sets, so the relevant notion of isomorphism is that of simplicial sets, not topological spaces.

Comment: @ZhenLin I see. What's the functor between simplicial sets and simplicial complexes you're using? It's not the standard realization functor to spaces.

Comment: I do not see where simplicial complexes enter the question as written. Can you restate your question in words instead of symbols?

Comment: @ZhenLin They don't enter my original question, but you mentioned the notion of simplicial isomorphism, which is an iso in the category of simplicial complexes with simplicial maps, right? If the iso of hom-sets is natural, then we have $\Delta[n+1] \cong \Delta[n] \times \Delta[1]$, but how do we transfer this to an iso in a category with simplicial maps as morphisms?

Comment: I never mentioned the phrase "simplicial isomorphism" nor alluded to simplicial complexes. You wrote $\textbf{sSet}$. That denotes the category of simplicial sets. If there is a natural isomorphism of hom-sets as you wrote, then $\Delta^n \times \Delta^1$ – a simplicial set – would be isomorphic to $\Delta^{n+1}$ – another simplicial set, but these are not isomorphic.